# nlme gls different AR(1) correlations for two groups

Tags: lme4-nlme, autocorrelation, generalized-least-squares

I'm using the gls procedure of package nlme in R. Is it possible to specify that two different correlation matrices (Ar1 to start with but also, compound symmetry, Toeplitz and unstructured) should be estimated for two groups of respondents, men and women? Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

If you means that you want the autoregressive process to have different correlation coefficients between two groups, then no. To have autocorrelation, you specify the model by `lme(y ~ x, correlation = corAR1(form = ~ time | id)` which estimates an autocorrelation coefficient that is shared by all individuals between two adjacent times of measurements. It might be possible to allow this autocorrelation coefficient to vary by group, but it should require some hacking. This answer has a worked example showing this possibility https://stackoverflow.com/a/76823387/20653759

I would instead use sex or gender as a predictor of the mean structure.